# Join 2 div's with a box with perspective

Tags: html, css

Looking to create a ribbon like so:

[image]

Currently, my attempt looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code that I've written to product that:

```css
.ribbon {
  width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px; //remove any margins to prevent breaking at each element
  box-sizing:border-box; //allow paddings to not interfere with element width 
}

.front {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 45%;
  background: #EA0B1D;
  border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.middle {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 5%;
  background: #B1071D;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(45deg);
}

.back {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  width: 45%;
  background: #EA0B1D;
  border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

span {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">
  <div class="front">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also see the result on my JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4wv3csfy/3/)

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some difference between the image you posted and the code you have: will the two elements have different height? Because that will change how the solution will be. If they're the same height, using skew to transform the ribbon connector will work. Otherwise, you might have to use JS to draw an SVG path for that. Using perspective is difficult because you need to take into account both the size of the ribbon, the coordinates of the edges, and compute the correct transformation matrix for that.

Comment: @Terry Doesn't have to perfectly have the same height, just something similar. What I'm mainly looking for is the connection of the two divs.

Comment: If that is the case, using perspective is probably not the right way to go about it: it requires too many variables. Basically, you need a mathematical model that will compute (1) the perspective value, (2) the dimensions of the ribbon, (3) the rotation angle, (4) transform origin. Will you be willing to accept a JS-based solution for that?

Comment: See the second half of my first comment.

Comment: @Terry JS is perfectly fine to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your solution.

First thing i noticed is that instead of skewing along the x-axis, you should skew 45 degrees along the y-axis.

```
transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(45deg);
```

This will give you the desired shape for the middle part.

Then it's just a matter of aligning the shapes using margins inside `.middle` and `.back` class.

```css
.ribbon {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.front {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 45%;
  background: #EA0B1D;
  border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.middle {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 5%;
  margin-top: 5px;                               /* added this line */
  background: #B1071D;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(45deg);          /* changed skewX to skewY */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(45deg);  /* changed skewX to skewY */
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(45deg);      /* changed skewX to skewY */
}

.back {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 10px;                              /* changed 15px to 10px */
  margin-right: 10px;                            /* added this line */
  width: 45%;
  background: #EA0B1D;
  border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

span {
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon">
  <div class="front">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer! You might get more upvotes if you explain before or inside the code what you have changed. It's easy to see you added `margin-top` but it took me a while to see that you changed `skewX ` to `skewY`. If possible point out all changes you've made.

Comment: Thanks, i will improve my answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Selected as the solution :)